# IndexError: index 13132 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

#There is data:[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ai5jiz_oT-LTaUF6ViSCWpy9I83ThzTV/view?usp=sharing)

I am a novice trying to solve this problem,here is the code:

```
 def average_influenza_doses():
 df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\NISPUF17 (1).csv")
 df = df[['CBF_01', 'P_NUMFLU']]
 df = df.isna().sum()
 df = df[df['P_NUMFLU']].notna()
 tot1 = len(df[df['CBF_01'] == 1])
 tot2 = len(df[df['CBF_01'] == 2])
 mi = df[df['CBF_01'] == 1]['P_NUMFLU'].sum()
 notmi = df[df['CBF_01'] == 2]['P_NUMFLU'].sum()
 return (mi/tot1, notmi/tot2)
print(average_influenza_doses())

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Assignment2.py", 
line 41, in <module>
print(average_influenza_doses())
File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Assignment2.py", 
line 35, in average_influenza_doses
df = df[df['P_NUMFLU']].notna()
File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 939, in __getitem__
return self._values[key]
IndexError: index 13132 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

If anyone has other ways to code, please give me suggestions, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your problem is that you are re-assign df to a pd.Series with    `df.isna().sum()`, then you select a single element from this pd.Series using `df['P_NUMFLI']` which returns a single scalar value with dtype of np.int64. That object doesn't have a method notna().

Comment: Thank for your advice already update the details.

Answer (score -2):

Notna should be applied on dataframes. It should be

`df[df['P_NUMFLU']].notna()`

Also remove the below line from code:

```
df=df.isna().sum()
```

Comment: @ININCHEN Please check updated comment. Remove the line mentioned in comment.

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion, it been work.

Comment: @ININCHEN does above suggestions helped you?